# How to add content-language

Tags: 7, meta-tags

How can i add this meta tag in my website :

`<meta http-equiv=“content-language” content=“en-us”>`     ?

I am using metatags module but i dont see any option about this. Is there any other way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7, you can achieve it using **template_page_alter**

    `function THEME_NAME_page_alter($page) {
        global $language;
        $lang_name = $language->language;
        $meta_language = array(
          '#type' => 'html_tag',
          '#tag' => 'meta',
          '#attributes' => array(
            'http-equiv' => 'content-language',
            'content' => $lang_name
          )
        );
        $meta_content_language = array(
          '#type' => 'html_tag',
          '#tag' => 'meta',
          '#attributes' => array(
            'http-equiv' => 'language',
            'content' => $lang_name
          )
        );
        drupal_add_html_head($meta_language, 'content-language');
        drupal_add_html_head($meta_content_language, 'language');
    }`

- Folder listing of **active theme** folder

  [image]
- **template_page_alter** inside **template.php** file

  [image]

[Source](https://drupal.org/node/272814#comment-5861000)

Comment: I am newbie, where do i put this code?

Comment: Go to your **ACTIVE theme** - **template.php** file and add paste the above function. And don't forget to change THEME_NAME with your **ACTIVE theme**.

Comment: I have updated my answer check it.

Comment: It doesnt seems to work. I double checked if i did correct...

Comment: Your welcome, enjoy :)